# Custom sidenav in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, custom-component

I want to create a custom sidenav in angular 2 (Not using angular material design). How to do this?
Is there any way to define CSS inside directive. Does using directive is a good ideal?

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'may-cover'
})

export class MayCover {
    constructor(
        private elRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer
    ) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef, 'height', '100%');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef, 'width', '100%');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef, 'transition', '0.5s');
    }

    open() {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef, 'margin-top', '0%');
    }

    close() {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef, 'margin-top', '-100%');
    }
}
```

Since

```
<may-cover #sidenav>...</may-cover>
```

I don't want to use `div`. It looks like a mess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like one would do that in Angular2

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: 'may-cover',
    host: {
      '[style.height.%]': '100',
      '[style.width.%]': '100',
      '[style.transition.s]': '0.5',
    }
})
export class MayCover {

  @HostBinding('style.margin-top.%')
  marginTop:number;

  open() {
    this.marginTop = 0;
  }

  close() {
    this.marginTop = 100;
  }
}
```

or

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: 'may-cover',
    styles: [`
      :host {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        transition:0.5s;
       }`],
    }
})
export class MayCover {

  @HostBinding('style.margin-top.%')
  marginTop:number;

  open() {
    this.marginTop = 0;
  }

  close() {
    this.marginTop = 100;
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XoCeUN9tbA7YHSVPJQjv?p=preview)